# Real valued function which is continuous only on transcendental numbers

Tags: real-analysis, transcendental-numbers, continuity

First of all, I am sorry for asking this question.

We know that $R$ is uncountable. And also the set of all **transcendental numbers** is uncountable. 
How can I construct a function $f(x)$ on $R$ which is continuos only at transcendental numbers? Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: try to adapt [Thomae's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function) to the algebraic numbers.

Comment: But thomae function is continuos at all irrational points. I need in specific that the function which is continuos only at transcendental numbers. Moreover Thomae function having only countable number of discontinuities. But I am expecting a function which having uncountable number of discontinuities as well as in uncountable number of continuities.

Comment: My point is that there is a function with the properties you want that has a similar form to Thomae's function, and am giving you a chance to figure out what it is for yourself. Also the set of algebraic numbers is countable, so your proposed function will have a countable number of discontinuities.

Comment: @eyeballfrog yes I agree with you sir. But my proposed function will have uncountable number of discontinuities. Because the set of all irrational number is uncountable and the set of all transcendental numbers is uncountable and the set of all irrational numbers which are not transcendental is also uncountable.

Comment: Exercise.  Prove the set of algebraic numbers is countable.

Comment: To make use of @eyeballfrog's hint, it might be conceptually simpler to adapt Thomae's function to an arbitrary countable dense subset of the reals, something like this: (a) enumerate the countable dense set as $a_1,$ $a_2,$ $\dots$ (b) define the function to have the value $\frac{1}{n}$ at $x = x_n$ (c) define the function to be zero for real numbers not belonging to the given countable dense set (d) prove this function has the properties you want it to have.

Comment: Explain @WilliamElliot comment.  A set $A \subseteq \mathbb R$ is the set of points of continuity for some function if and only if $A$ is a $G_\delta$-set.  The set of transcendental numbers is obviously a $G_\delta$, since its complement is countable

Answer (score 0):

You have had some strong hints. Here's an even stronger one.  Start with Thomae's function:

f(x) =

\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{q},  & \text{if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $x = \frac{p}{q} \land p \in \mathbb{Z} \land q \in \mathbb{N} \land p,q$ coprime} \\
0, & \text{if $x \notin \mathbb{Q}$}
\end{cases}

You need to understand why this works first.  The idea is for $\epsilon > 0$ there are only finitely many values of $q$ such that $\frac{1}{q} \geq \epsilon$.

Now you need to add a case for the algebraic numbers.

f(x) =

\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{q},  & \text{if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $x = \frac{p}{q} \land p \in \mathbb{Z} \land q \in \mathbb{N} \land p,q$ coprime} \\
?, & \text{if $x \notin \mathbb{Q} \land  x \in \mathbb{A}$} \\
0, & \text{if $x \notin \mathbb{A}$}
\end{cases}

So, you need a suitable value for that ?, what value will work for algebraic numbers?  You can use an idea similar the rationals.  First, remember what an algebraic number is: it is the root of a non-zero polynomial with rational coefficients.  Let $n$ be the lowest degree of any such polynomial.  Can you see how to use $n$ similarly to how $q$ is used for the rational case?

Comment: This is the first time that I have used cases in MathJax.  I started with a copy of the example from the tutorial but the function name $f(x)$ is not positioned as neatly as I would like.

Comment: Here's what I do in cases like this, namely when I want to format something and don't know how, and I'm pretty sure it can be done because I've seen it before. Think of a word or phrase that is likely to appear when whatever you're looking for is used, then search in Mathematics Stackexchange (the search window is at the top left of my screen) or search in google with "site:math.stackexchange.com" (omit quotes) included. In your example, I would guess what you want will often be in questions involving [piecewise defined functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=piecewise+defined).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thanks.  I have done that before, I'll have a go later when I am less busy.

Answer (score 0):

I think one can also proceed as follows:
Define the step function $\psi: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by 
\begin{equation*}
\psi(x) = \begin{cases}
               1 \text{ if } x \geq 0\\
               0 \text{ otherwise}
          \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
Let $a_{1},a_{2},\dots$ be an enumeration of all algebraic integers and let 
\begin{equation*}
  f(x) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}2^{-n}\psi(x-a_{n}).
\end{equation*}